# why mysql query select from two tables by " IN " is slow query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a two table contains customer id like this :

```
(SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cellular = '$cellular' OR  id  IN(SELECT customer FROM clients WHERE number=$cellular  ) )
```

when i search for customer cellular client  OR  cellular this mysql query take a 30 seconds .
how i can to be more fast?

Comment: Without knowing your table structures (with indexes), explain output, number of rows in both tables, how do you expect us to answer this question?

Comment: customers = 2447 rows with id index
clients  = 1102 rows with customer index
customers.id and clients.customer is same number

Comment: Where is the explain output? Are cellular and number fields indexed in the 2 tables? But honestly, even if they are not indexed, mysql should not have a problem with 3.5k rows, so the issue may be somewhere else (mysql configuration?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MySQL `join`

```
SELECT * FROM customers left join clients 
on customers.id=clients.customer 
where clients.number=$cellular or customers.cellular = '$cellular'
```

or try this query :-

```
SELECT * FROM customers inner join clients 
on customers.id=clients.customer 
where clients.number=$cellular or customers.cellular = '$cellular'
```

Comment: thank you man ! you helped me and the mysql query very faster ! thank you

Comment: it's my pleasure :) @QadahMohammed